# handle_info/2 doesn't get the message sent by Python when cast a message using ErlPort and GenServer

Tags: python, elixir, gen-server

I am trying to mix Elixir with Python using [ErlPort](http://erlport.org/), so I decided to read some tutorials about it and the documentation related about everything involved. I understand how works the logic and what does each function. However, I am having problems casting a message and receiving the Python response.

Based on what I read and what I have done I understand that when I cast a message with `cast_count/1`, this is handle by `handle_cast/2` and then is handle by the Python function `handle_message()` and then this one cast the message with the function `cast_message()` and the imported one `cast()`from `erlport.erlang`. Finally, Elixir should handle the message received from Python with `handle_info/2`. I think this function is not being executed but I don't know the reason, although I have investigated a lot this stuff in different sources and in the documentation of GenServer and ErlPort.

In my case I have the next structure: `lib/python_helper.ex` to make ErlPort works and `lib/server.ex` to call and cast the Python functions.

`lib/python_helper.ex`

```
defmodule WikiElixirTest.PythonHelper do
  def start_instance do
    path =
      [:code.priv_dir(:wiki_elixir_test), "python"]
      |> Path.join()
      |> to_charlist()

    {:ok, pid} = :python.start([{:python_path, path}])
    pid
  end

  def call(pid, module, function, arguments \\ []) do
    pid
    |> :python.call(module, function, arguments)
  end

  def cast(pid, message) do
    pid
    |> :python.cast(message)
  end

  def stop_instance(pid) do
    pid
    |> :python.stop()
  end
end
```

`lib/server.ex`

```
defmodule WikiElixirTest.Server do
  use GenServer
  alias WikiElixirTest.PythonHelper

  def start_link() do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
  end

  def init(_args) do
    session = PythonHelper.start_instance()
    PythonHelper.call(session, :counter, :register_handler, [self()])

    {:ok, session}
  end

  def cast_count(count) do
    {:ok, pid} = start_link()
    GenServer.cast(pid, {:count, count})
  end

  def call_count(count) do
    {:ok, pid} = start_link()
    GenServer.call(pid, {:count, count}, :infinity)
  end

  def handle_call({:count, count}, _from, session) do
    result = PythonHelper.call(session, :counter, :counter, [count])
    {:reply, result, session}
  end

  def handle_cast({:count, count}, session) do
    PythonHelper.cast(session, count)
    {:noreply, session}
  end

  def handle_info({:python, message}, session) do
    IO.puts("Received message from Python: #{inspect(message)}")
    {:stop, :normal, session}
  end

  def terminate(_reason, session) do
    PythonHelper.stop_instance(session)
    :ok
  end
end
```

`priv/python/counter.py`

```py
import time
import sys
from erlport.erlang import set_message_handler, cast
from erlport.erlterms import Atom

message_handler = None


def cast_message(pid, message):
    cast(pid, (Atom('python', message)))


def register_handler(pid):
    global message_handler
    message_handler = pid


def handle_message(count):
    try:
        print('Received message from Elixir')
        print(f'Count: {count}')
        result = counter(count)
        if message_handler:
            cast_message(message_handler, result)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass


def counter(count=100):
    i = 0
    data = []
    while i < count:
        time.sleep(1)
        data.append(i+1)
        i = i + 1

    return data


set_message_handler(handle_message)
```

**Note**: I removed `@doc` to light the code snippets. And yes, I know `sys` isn't being used at this moment and that catch `Exception` in Python `try` block is not the best approach, it is just temporal.

If I test it in `iex` (`iex -S mix`), I get the next:

```
iex(1)>  WikiElixirTest.Server.cast_count(19)
Received message from Elixir
Count: 19
:ok
```

I want to note that `call_count/1` and `handle_call/1` works fine:

```
iex(3)>  WikiElixirTest.Server.call_count(10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

What I am doing wrong that the communication of Elixir with Python is successful but not the communication of Python with Elixir when I cast a message?

Comment: Maybe the `cast(pid, (Atom('python', message)))` should be `cast(pid, (Atom('python'), message))` ? But that's just a guess... I have never heard of ErlPort.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Everett, for pointing this error. I must have this bad typing after the many times I tried to fix it. However, now I am getting too the message `bytes object expected`, so I am getting a response. Looking at the code of ErlPort in its repository, I found this error message in [erlterms.py](https://github.com/hdima/erlport/blob/master/priv/python3/erlport/erlterms.py#L66) and I discovered the error. I am going to answer my own question. Again, thank you very much, Everett.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, @Everett reported in the question that I closed wrong the atom in `counter.py`.

```py
def cast_message(pid, message):
    cast(pid, (Atom('python', message)))
```

This must be:

```py
def cast_message(pid, message):
    cast(pid, (Atom('python'), message))
```

Although this doesn't solve the problem, it helps me to get with the solution. After fixed the first part (`(Atom('python'), message)`), when I execute `cast_count/1` I get a message from Python:

```
iex(1)> WikiElixirTest.Server.cast_count(2)
Received message from Elixir
Count: 2
:ok
bytes object expected
```

Although it confuses me a bit at the first time because I awaited something like "Received message from Python: bytes object expected", due `handle_info/2`. However, I decided to inspect the code of ErlPort and I found the error in [the line 66 of `erlterms.py`](https://github.com/hdima/erlport/blob/master/priv/python3/erlport/erlterms.py#L66), part of the `Atom` class. Thus the error was in the first part of the message, the atom, so I specified it as binary:

```py
def cast_message(pid, message):
    cast(pid, (Atom(b'python', message)))
```

Then I checked it:

```
iex(2)> WikiElixirTest.Server.cast_count(2)
:ok
Received message from Elixir        
Count: 2        
Received message from Python: [[1, 2]]
```

And it works nicely! So the problem there, even taking into account my mistyping of the message tuple, was that `Atom()` needs a binary.

Probably this misunderstanding may be due the first [ErlPort tutorial](https://medium.com/hackernoon/mixing-python-with-elixir-ii-async-e8586f9b2d53) I followed uses Python 2, version in which `str` is a string of bytes and in Python 3 it would be necessary to convert the string to bytes, due `str` is a string of text.